# Visual Studio TFS build with code coverage

Tags: visual-studio, build, code-coverage

Essentially what I would like to do is write a visual studio build script that will only build the solution if my code coverage requirements have been met.

So essentially, after compiling and running the automated testing of the solution, I want to pass the build (working with Team Foundation server) only if a certain % of the code is covered by testing.

Any input is highly valued; resources, a solution, or even "that's impossible"

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but for someone else looking at this post the following blog post explains how to do it

[Fail a Build if Code Coverage is Low](http://scrumdod.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/fail-build-if-code-coverage-is-low.html)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282652/fail-a-build-if-code-coverage-is-below-a-threshold-in-tfs2012/16198120#16198120 for how to do this on TFS 2012.